# Nginx Regular expression to match first segment of a url

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have some urls like these:

```
domain.com/article/1234-newstitle
domain.com/article/1234-newstitle/
domain.com/article/1234-newstitle/abc
domain.com/article/1234-newstitle/xpto/abc
domain.com/article/1234-newstitle/qwerty/abc/xyz
```

I want to catch only the /**1234**-**newstitle**/ to redirect these urls and ignore everything after the 1º slash (whatever the number of segments) so I can have:

```
domain.com/news/newstitle-1234/
```

The best I could get is:

```
rewrite ^article/(\d+)-(.*)[^\/]* /new/$2-$1/ permanent;
```

but $2 matches everything after 1234-

How am I able to match only the first segment "1234-newstitle" and ignore the rest?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got a greedy match after the hyphen. Try this:

```
rewrite ^/article/(\d+)-([^/]+) /new/$2-$1/ permanent;
```